# Search in table and its translation table

Tags: symfony, internationalization, doctrine

I was writing a search function, which using dql to fetch results from a table **product**. 
And Product has its translation table, I want to fetch the translation table results as well, how can I achieve that?

translation table annotation:

`/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="product_translations", indexes={
 *      @ORM\Index(name="product_translation_idx", columns={"locale", "object_class", "field", "foreign_key"})
 * })
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\Repository\TranslationRepository")
 */`

Here is my dql:
`$dql = 'SELECT p
            FROM CSOBackendBundle:Product p
            WHERE p.content LIKE :searchParam';
            $query = $em->createQuery($dql)->setParameter('searchParam', '%' . $searchParam . '%');
            $result = $query->getResult();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a relation to the translation table in your Product entity.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: The translation table is already have relation with product. What should I do next?  `/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="products_translations", indexes={
 *      @ORM\Index(name="products_translation_idx", columns={"locale", "object_class", "field", "foreign_key"})
 * })
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\Repository\TranslationRepository")
 */`

Comment: I see you use Translatable, I think you should check out the example here: https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md